# why this comparison's output is TRUE

Tags: php, oop

this is the code:

```
class university {
  function hello($name){
    return $this->name;
  }

}

function compare1(&$obj1 , $obj2){
  if ($obj1 === $obj2) {
       return TRUE;
  }else {
    return FALSE;
  }
}

}

$uni1 = new university();
$uni2 = new university();
$uni3 =  $uni1;

 echo  compare1($uni1 , $uni3)  ?"SAME" : "DIFFERENT";
```

I want to know why the output is **SAME** ,although the compare function take the first parameter by refrence and the second by value, so the identity operator must gives us FALSE.
Also if we try to make this:

```
$uni3 =  clone $uni1;

 echo  compare1($uni1 , $uni3)  ?"SAME" : "DIFFERENT";
```

the output is **DIFFERENT** .
knowing that both example are equal .right?

Answer (score 0):

```
$uni3 =  $uni1;
```

Here the value have been passed by reference, so of course when compare they are the same object.

```
$uni3 =  clone $uni1;
```

Here you've made a shallow copy, so the references are different then the result will be not the same.